# With KStreams, how do I unit test UncaughtExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a very simple uncaught exception handler that I set on my streams, and it works when the app is running as normal.

`streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(uncaughtExceptionHandler);`

It doesn't get triggered from JUnit, though. I moved the actual test body into a separate thread so that my RuntimeException does not make the test instantly fail.

```
Thread testThread = new Thread(() -> {

            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, APPLICATION_ID);
            config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_CONFIG);
            config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

            recordFactory = new ConsumerRecordFactory<>(Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.String().serializer());

            topology = createTestTopology();
            testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, config);

            UserTransactionService userTransactionService =
                    new UserTransactionService(topology,
                            Serdes.String(),
                            KAFKA_CONFIGURATION,
                            uncaughtExceptionHandler);
            userTransactionService.init();

            verify(KAFKA_CONFIGURATION, times(1)).getApplicationId();
            verify(KAFKA_CONFIGURATION, times(1)).getBootstrapServersConfig();

            boolean exceptionWasThrown = false;
            try {
                testDriver.pipeInput(recordFactory.create(KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC_NAME, "k", "v", System.currentTimeMillis()));
//                pushDataToKafka("key", "value");
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // O. Expected behaviour.
                exceptionWasThrown = true;
            }

            try {
                assertThat(exceptionWasThrown, is(equalTo(false))); //this is fine
// But this will fai, meaning it never calls uncaught exception handler:
//                verify(uncaughtExceptionHandler, times(1)).uncaughtException(any(Thread.class),
//                        any(Throwable.class));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
        });

        testThread.start();
        testThread.join();
```

The topology is coded to throw an exception:

```
    private Topology createTestTopology() {
        Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> stream = builder.stream(KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC_NAME,
                Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
        stream.mapValues(value -> {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        });
        stream.to(KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME, Produced.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Is there a way to test that this gets called at all?

Comment: It is not possible to test this, and there is no reason for a user to test it.

Comment: Hi @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for your answer. I would like to test it does indeed kick in for uncaught exceptions.

Comment: You can only test this, if you call `KafkaStreams#start()` and let a thread really die.